# Piping a file to a different stream

Tags: node.js, audio-streaming

I'm reading a audio file with `growing-file` and piping it to a writable stream as follows:

```
var GrowingFile = require('growing-file')
var audio = GrowingFile.open('test.wav')
audio.pipe(<some writable stream>);
```

After a few minutes I would like to change where the stream is being piped to.

I've tried to just create a second `audio.pipe(<new writable stream>)` however this just writes to two streams now. How would I go about killing the first stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the optimal solution but this worked for me:

```
var GrowingFile = require('growing-file')
var unpipe = require('unpipe');
var audio = GrowingFile.open('test.wav')
audio.pipe(<some writable stream>);

//later in code
unpipe(audio);
audio.pipe(<some new writable stream>);
```

Answer (score 0):

See [`readable.unpipe([destination])`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_unpipe_destination)

```
var GrowingFile = require('growing-file')
var audio = GrowingFile.open('test.wav')
var writeableStream = <some writable stream>
audio.pipe(writeableStream);

setTimeout(() => {
  audio.unpipe(writeableStream)
  writeableStream = <some other writable stream>
  audio.pipe(writeableStream)
}, 60000)
```